# Finatra in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, scala, tomcat, netty, finagle

I have some questions on Finatra and Tomcat. As a requirement I have to be able to package a Finatra app in a .WAR file and deploy it to a Tomcat server.

1. Can it be done? I guess it would be similar to hosting other netty-based servers inside tomcat, but I'm not sure if that's possible either. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194508/is-hosting-a-netty-server-inside-tomcat-feasible-desirable) suggests it possible.
2. What would be the best way to go about that if possible?

Things I've tried:

1. Using a proxyservlet. This kinda works, but I can't get the Finatra server to start up correctly from code.
2. Running a jar that contains the Finatra server from the Servlet ini method.

Answer (score 0):

A custom [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) would be an appropriate place to start/stop embedded netty servers.